# Casting a list of objects to another one

Tags: c#, linq, casting, lambda, dao

I have the following classes(entities): Entity(base class, has 3 props) & Category(derives from Entity and adds some other props)

The problem occurs when I read data from the DB(the fill method returns a list of Entities) and the compiler doesn't allow me to cast from Entity to Category.

The problematic code:

```
var categories = (Category)categoryDao.Read();
```

I can do the process in a very different way though:

```
var categories = new List<Category>();
foreach (var item in categoryDao.Read())
{
    categories.Add((Category)item);
}
```

But it's probably bad and unnecessary. So, the question is, can I do this in a more simple way using LINQ + LAMBDA, or there are other tricks?

Comment: What is the return type of `Read()`?

Comment: You may take a look at ``IEnumerable`1.Cast`1()`` and ``IEnumerable`1.ToList()``

Comment: @haim770: probably ``Entity``

Comment: @haim770 it is of type Entity (I've mentioned it above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `Read()` is probably something like `IEnumerable<Entity>` or `List<Entity>`. That's why you can't cast them to a single `Category`.

If you need a one line solution for this, you could try

```
var categories = categoryDao.Read().OfType<Category>();
```

or (thanks @Binkan Salaryman)

```
var categories = categoryDao.Read().Cast<Category>();
```

(the former will return only the elements which are of type `Category` - the latter will throw an exception if there are elements which cannot be cast into `Category`)